# AJAX form sending multiple POST requests, no data, in node/express

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I'm trying to teach myself the MEAN stack by making the proverbial to-do list. Everything is working great, except my form appears to send multiple POST requests on one click. I'm sending through a simple bit of JSON that contains the to-do task and tags. These do what they're supposed to and appear on the page. But at the same time, one or more (I can' seem to find a pattern)* unwanted additional POST requests send through empty versions of the same JSON,resulting in blank entries being posted to the site.

I'm using Express in Node.js and MongoDB on MongoLab via Heroku.

*app.js*

```
    var main = function(toDoObjects) {
    "use strict";

    var toDos = toDoObjects.map(function(todo) {
        return todo.description;
    });

    console.log(toDos);

    //Create an empty array of tabs
    var tabs = [];

    //Add the 'Newest' tab    
    tabs.push({
        "name":"Newest",
        "content":function(callback) {
            $.get("todos.json", function(toDoObjects) {
                var $content;

                $content = $("<ul>");   
                for (var i = toDos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    $content.append($("<li>").text(toDos[i]));
                }    

            callback($content);

            });
        }
    });

    //Add the 'Oldest' tab
    tabs.push({
        "name":"Oldest",
        "content":function(callback) {
            $.get("todos.json", function(toDoObjects) {

                var $content;

                $content = $("<ul>");
                toDos.forEach(function(todo) {
                    $content.append($("<li>").text(todo));
                });

            callback($content);

            });
        }
    });

    //Add the 'Tags' tab
    tabs.push({
        "name":"Tags",
        "content":function(callback) {
            $.get("todos.json", function(toDoObjects) {


                var theTags, $content; 

                theTags = [];

                $content = $("<div>");

                toDoObjects.forEach(function(toDos) {

                    // Build array of unique tags
                    toDos.tags.forEach(function(tag) {

                        if (theTags.indexOf(tag) === -1)
                            theTags.push(tag);

                    });
                }); 

                //Map toDos onto tags
                var newToDoList = theTags.map(function(theTag) {

                    var toDosWithTag = [];

                    toDoObjects.forEach( function(toDos) {
                        if (toDos.tags.indexOf(theTag) !== -1) 
                            toDosWithTag.push(toDos.description);
                    });

                    return { "name" : theTag, "toDos" : toDosWithTag };
                }); 

                newToDoList.forEach(function(tag) {
                    var $tagName = $("<h3 class='tag-header'>").text(tag.name);
                    var $taggedTasks = $("<ul class='tags'>");

                    tag.toDos.forEach(function(description) {
                        var $li = $("<li>").text(description);
                        $taggedTasks.append($li);
                    });

                    $content.append($tagName);
                    $content.append($taggedTasks);
                });

            callback($content);

            });          
        }       
    });

    //Add the 'Add' tab
    tabs.push({
        "name":"Add",
        "content":function(callback) {
 //           $.get("todos.json", function(toDoObjects) {

                var $input,$inputLabel,$tagInput,$tagLabel,$button,$content;    

                $input = $("<input>").addClass("description"),
                $inputLabel = $("<p>").text("Description: "),
                $tagInput = $("<input>").addClass("tags"),
                $tagLabel = $("<p>").text("Tags: "),
                $button = $("<button>").text("+");

                $content = $("<div>").append($inputLabel)
                                     .append($input)
                                     .append($tagLabel)
                                     .append($tagInput)
                                     .append($button);

                $(".content").on("click", "button", function() {

                    var description = $input.val(),
                        tags = $tagInput.val().split(","),
                        newToDo = {"description": description, "tags": tags};
                        console.log(newToDo);

                    if ($(".description").val() !== "" && $(".tags").val() !== "" ) {

                        //example post to todos route
                        $.post("todos", newToDo, function(result) {
                            // this callback is called when the server responds
                            console.log(result);

                            toDos = result.map(function(todo) {
                                    return todo.description;
                            });

                            console.log(toDos);    

                            $input.val("");
                            $tagInput.val("");

                        });
                    }
                });

                $(".content").on("keypress", "input", function(event) {
                    if (event.keyCode === 13) {

                        var description = $input.val(),
                            tags = $tagInput.val().split(","),
                            newToDo = {"description": description, "tags": tags};

                        if ($(".description").val() !== "" && $(".tags").val() !== "" ) {

                            $.post("todos", newToDo, function(result) {
                                 // this callback is called when the server responds
                                console.log(result);

                                toDos = result.map(function(todo) {
                                        return todo.description;
                                });

                                console.log(toDos);    

                                $input.val("");
                                $tagInput.val("");

                            });
                        }
                    }
                });

            callback($content);

 //           });
        }    
    });


    tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
        var $aElement = $("<a>").attr("href",""),
            $spanElement = $("<span>").text(tab.name);

        $aElement.append($spanElement);

        $spanElement.on("click", function() {

            $(".tabs a span").removeClass("active"); //make all tabs inactive         
            $spanElement.addClass("active"); //make clicked tab active
            $("main .content").empty(); //empty the content

            //send callback
            tab.content(function($content) { 
                $("main .content").append($content);
            });

            return false;
        });

        $("main .tabs").append($aElement);

    });

   $(".tabs a:first-child span").trigger("click");

};  

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("toDos.json", function(toDoObjects) {
        main(toDoObjects);
    });
});
```

*server.js*

```
    var express = require("express"),
    http = require("http"),
    //import the mongoose library
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    uriUtil = require("mongodb-uri"),
    app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client"));

// Tell Express to parse incoming JSON objects
app.use(express.urlencoded());

// Set Mongoose options
var options = { server: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 } }, 
                replset: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS : 30000 } } };  

//MongoLab variables
var mongodbUri = 'mongodb://<REDACTED>';
var mongooseUri = uriUtil.formatMongoose(mongodbUri);

// Connect to the Amazeriffic data store in mongo
mongoose.connect(mongodbUri, options);

// Mongoose model for todos
var ToDoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    description: String,
    tags: [ String ]
});

var ToDo = mongoose.model("ToDo", ToDoSchema);

// Now listen for requests -- env variable for Heroku port assignment
http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get("/todos.json", function(req, res) {
    ToDo.find({}, function(err, toDos) {
        res.json(toDos);
    });
}); 

app.post("/todos", function(req, res) {
    // The object is now stored in req.body
    console.log(req.body);
    var newToDo = new ToDo({"description":req.body.description,
                            "tags":req.body.tags});
    newToDo.save(function(err, result) {
        if (err !== null) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send("ERROR");
        } else {
            // additional request to ensure compatibility
            // client expects entire list to be returned
            ToDo.find({}, function(err, result) {
                if (err !== null) {
                    //the element didn't get saved
                    res.send("ERROR");
                }
                res.json(result);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

***Edit:** Looks like there's a pattern, after all. The first click adds an entry. The second click adds an entry plus one blank. The third click adds an entry plus two blanks, and so on. So clearly I've messed up the logic somewhere.

Comment: You have a number of AJAX functionalities shown here.  Can you narrow down for us which one(s) you are having problems with?

Comment: Sorry, it's the POST request in the "'Add' tab" in app.js (line 136 in the original code). I have both 'click' and 'keypress' events set up to fire the request. The form has two fields, 'description' and 'tags.' These are both wired to the one POST route in server.js.

Comment: You have a comment about parsing JSON, but the middleware being used is for `express.urlencoded()`. Perhaps you should try `express.json()` instead?

Comment: I managed to find a fix, though I can't quite explain why it works. I was assigning the event handler sending the POST request directly to selectors in the DOM -- `$(".content").on("click", "button", function() { ... ` -- rather than to the variable in my function generating the HTML -- `$button.on("click", function() { ...` Making the switch eliminated the multiple POST requests. I recognize this has something to do with event delegation and bubbling, but I'm still getting my head around these concepts.